# Salesforce to an external Service callout using JWT

Tags: apex, integration, callout, jwt

Hi Community Members,

The ask is to call a service, from Salesforce that will accept only requests that are based on JWT. Precise wording is

> Salesforce sends an encrypted JWT object containing the sensitive data in JSON format

There is a lot of information available on JWT formatted requests targeted at Salesforce, but here the need is to send JWT encrypted requests from Salesforce.

I would like to know how that could be achieved. Normal rest callouts include creating the request body structure, having the endpoint, and then simply sending the request from Salesforce. So what is the procedure for this situation.

I would highly appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: With the exception of very few scenarios, you won't be able to do this with out of the box Salesforce tools or classes. [Implementing crypto on your own is an absolute no-no](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209652/why-is-it-wrong-to-implement-myself-a-known-published-widely-believed-to-be). You have 2 choices: do it in JS on the client and incorporate it into your larger SF-based solution via Visualforce or Lightning or call out to another platform. In either case you'll want to rely on published and reviewed crypto libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of JWTs that I'm familiar with don't encrypt the claims (they just provide the claims along with a relatively simple way to verify that the claims haven't been tampered with. I suppose that this is technically then a JWS rather than a JWT). The [RFC for JWTs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519) suggests that the proper term for an "encrypted JWT" would be JWE (Json Web Encryption, with it's [own rfc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7516)).

There's not really much special about sending a JWT/JWE compared to sending any other data in a callout. You either put the JWT/JWE in the URL as (part of) a query string (GET requests), or put it into the body (POST requests).

The hardest part of the process would be generating the JWT/JWE payload.

Salesforce does provide [JWT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm) and [JWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWS.htm) classes in the Auth namespace which make this part trivial if you can use it (requires the certificate used to sign the JWT to be stored in Salesforce's "Certificate and Key Management")

```
Auth.JWT jwtExample = new Auth.JWT();
// There are methods to set/get most of the registered claim names
jwt.setSub('derek@company.tld');

// Additional claims are easy enough to add
jwtExample.setAdditionalClaims(new Map<String, Object>{
    'MyPrivateClaim1' => 'value',
    'AnotherClaim' => Date.today()
});

// The JWT methods just generate the claims/payload
// The JWS class handles creating the header, creating the signature, and base64url-encoding
//   the whole thing
Auth.JWS signedExample = new Auth.JWS(jwtExample, 'My_Cert_Name');

// getCompactSerialization gives you the data you'd include in the query 
//   string or body of your request (for an unencrypted JWT)
system.debug(signedExample.getCompactSerialization());

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
// Generally for GET requests
//req.setEndpoint('https://my.endpoint.com?claims=' + signedExample.getCompactSerialization());
// Generally for POST requests
//req.setBody(signedExample.getCompactSerialization());
```

You'd need to do more digging to find out what, precisely, your service means when they say "encrypted JWT", but assuming they're actually talking about sending a JWE, that's where you'll need to get your hands dirty. Salesforce doesn't provide any JWE class, so we'd need to do it ourselves.

This is the part where I venture outside of my knowledge base. Delving into the RFCs, Salesforce doesn't provide us with direct tools to perform the necessary encryption. I think our best shot would be to use AES256 and SHA512 to implement the crypto operations required for the ContentEncodingKey (A256KW) and encrypting the JWT payload (AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512).

I'm not nearly familiar enough with cryptography to be able to slap together a quick example, and don't have the time I'd need to learn how to implement those. If you do need a JWE, the best option would probably be to enlist the services of an intermediary server (such as a Heroku dyno, DigitalOcean droplet, etc...) where it's possible to find/install/use tools that implement JWE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Derek, this was a perfect explanation to clarify all my doubts.